# Why I get "Error: Could not find or load main class mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar "?

Tags: java, mysql, linux, jdbc

I installed MySQL in ubuntu 20.04 operating system.

```
Mysql version:-mysql  Ver 8.0.20-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 for Linux on x86_64 ((Ubuntu))
```

In my operating system Java open jdk-8 is installed.

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_252"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_252-8u252-b09-1ubuntu1-b09)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.252-b09, mixed mode)
```

I have writen a JDBC program to create table and save it in /workspace/jdbc/firstApplication directory and compiled it with javac filename.java and copy .jar file is the same directory upto this every thing is fine when i does

**java -cp .: mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar Fetchdata** 
i get:-

**Error: Could not find or load main class mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar**

I have posted program and compilation process below:-

**program:-**

```
import java.sql.*;
public class Fetchdata
{
        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
        {
                String driver="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver";
                String JDBC_URL=" jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/demodatabase";
                String user_name="root";
                String password="toor";
                String sql_query1="create table employee(eno number,ename varchar2(10),esal number(10,2),addr varchar2(10))";
                Class.forName(driver);
                Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection(JDBC_URL,user_name,password);
                Statement st=con.createStatement();
                st.executeUpdate(sql_query1);
                System.out.println("Table created Successfully");
                con.close();
        }
}
```

**compilation process:-**

```
atharva@focalfossa:~/workspace/jdbc/firstApplication$ javac Fetchdata.java
atharva@focalfossa:~/workspace/jdbc/firstApplication$ ls
atharva@focalfossa:~/workspace/jdbc/firstApplication$  java -cp .: mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar Fetchdata
Error: Could not find or load main class mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar
atharva@focalfossa:~/workspace/jdbc/firstApplication$
```

Is Java version, MySQL version and .jar are not suitable for each other or there is any problem with my code or some thing is related to my compilation process.

Comment: Remove the space between `.:` and `mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar`. The `mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar` is now taken as the class you want to run, not a library on the classpath.

Answer (score 0):

You have a space too much in your command line:

```
java -cp .: mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar Fetchdata
```

The space after `.:` means that your classpath consists of `.:` and the next token (mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar) is interpreted as name of the main class.

Use

```
java -cp .:mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar Fetchdata
```

to run your program.

Comment: should be split by using a semicolon?  *Specifies a list of directories, JAR files, and ZIP archives to search for class files. Separate class path entries with semicolons (;). Specifying -classpath or -cp overrides any setting of the CLASSPATH environment variable.*

Comment: @ScaryWombat that must have been changed recently, even the documentation for the java tool in version 14 (https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/specs/man/java.html) contains the phrase "then the class path element mydir/* is expanded to A.jar:b.JAR", separating the class path elements with a colon

Comment: @ScaryWombat Windows uses `;`, while Linux etc use `:`. Windows is the outlier, because of the `:` in drive letters.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Thanks, I kept on thinking that the docs weren't quite right.